# How to get list of an entity with generic search

Tags: c#, linq, generics, repository

I have a generic repository, something like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<T> SelectAll()
    {
        return table.ToList();
    }

    public T SelectByID(object id)
    {
        return table.Find(id);
    }

    public void Insert(T obj)
    {
        table.Add(obj);
    }
```

This works fine for the basic CRUD, but now I need to search an entity (table) against an user entered searchterm. Is it at all possible to do it with something like:

```
public IEnumerable<T> SelectAll(T obj, string searchText, string   columnName)
{
    // I am not sure what code to write here... It should give me all the records that contain the search term.
    // I was thinking something like this could be made to work...but I need help with it.
    return table.GetType().GetProperty(columnName).GetValue())ToList();
}
```

Comment: Use Dynamic Linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I am using now:

```
        public IEnumerable<T> SelectAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> searchResult = context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
        return searchResult;
    }
```

And the method call:

```
 var lstResult = objRepo.SelectAll(x=>x.ColumnName.Contains(searchText));
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a Lambda Expression as the argument

```
public virtual async Task<List<T>> SearchBy(Expression<Func<Table, bool>> searchBy)
{
    return await _ctx.Set<Table>().Where(searchBy).ToListAsync();
}
```

with this, you will call the search with a table expression argument returning a boolen

Comment: where is the column name in this? searchBy is the searchText, right?

Comment: you will call the method like this: SearchBy(i => i.ColumnName == searchText);

Comment: +the Table is the object/model you are searching...like, Movie, Book, etc

Comment: doesn't work, I get nothing in the list.  I get a whole bunch of stuff in the searchText except for the actual search string.